# Files bigger than max(off64_t) on Solaris, eg "/proc/../as"

Tags: process, solaris, 64bit, proc, x86

How do I read or seek from a file that's bigger than the maximum off64_t? The problem arises because the address space of a process is represented in the `/proc/.../as` file, which is a *huge* sparse file for 64-bit processes. It's really very big: on a sample process on Solaris x86-64, argv's address is 0xFFFFFD7FFFxxxxxx, that is, the very top of the address space is used. Pointers are unsigned, but an off64_t is signed, so can't reach anything in the top half of the address space file.

This obviously depends on the layout of the address space. On 32-bit systems, this isn't a problem (a `long` offset isn't big enough, but an `off64_t` easily works), and on x86-64 on linux (for example), the top of the process is 0x7fffxxxxxxxx (48 bits), so again an off64_t can refer to anything in the process's address space.

So, it's a shame that Solaris on x86-64 seems to use the whole 64-bit address space, when 50 bits is more than enough. Sun's examples of using psinfo_t.pr_argv just don't seem to work except on SPARC and x86. Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: Can't you `fseek` from SEEK_END with a negative offset?

Comment: I wish. It's not quite so straightforward. If we were to try and seek backwards from the end, we'd have to know the filesize. stat64 and ftello64 give me some slightly funny results; it's perhaps not quite as simple as pretending that the off64_t they give is infact a ulonglong. Example size output from fstat64 on the address space file is 0xFFFFFD7FFF1F28FA, but pr_argv is 0xFFFFFD7FFFDFFC98 (bigger!). (pr_argv is definitely correct: it matches `printf("%p", argv)` from within the process.

Comment: Interesting... sorry I don't have that sort of system available, so can't test anything here. I suppose two consecutive `fseek`s (one SEEK_SET to get to the "top half", then one SEEK_CUR to seek to where you want) doesn't work either?

Comment: Nevermind this comment,  misread

Comment: It's a bit odd. ftello64 has funny behaviour on very large files (bigger than an off64_t). If I seek to the end, I get no error from fseeko64, but ftello64 gives me 4726784 as the location, an honest positive number, not wrapped. Assuming I can use wizardly logic (eg inspect for negative fstat size) to "correct" it, it's not clear even what it's saying about the size of the file.

Comment: What if you use low-level I/O and lseek64 (with off64_t) or llseek (with offset_t, solaris-specific)? or simply pread64 to read without seeking? Note there is no low-level "tell" function, you just check the return and use 0,SEEK_CUR if you don't want to move.

Comment: Does `tail -c …` manage? What about `dd skip=…`?

Comment: Thanks, lseek returns much more sensible values than fseek. offset_t seems to be a holdover from an older implementation of LFS, but `lseek64(-500,SEEK_SET)` does seem to seek to 2**64-500. `tail` and `dd` can't handle offsets bigger than 2**63, as far as I could tell from playing around.

Comment: So, from [fixr](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/common/syscall/lseek.c?v=OPENSOLARIS#L274) it seems Solaris uses u_offset_t for filesizes internally (vattr), but stores the file_t offset in an offset_t which it allows to overflow without any checks. It seems to work, but I'd certainly accept any answer that can reassure me it's OK to do this... What if there are other things that might go wrong if the absolute offset is negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are on Solaris x86-64 some very large files, whose size exceeds 2<sup>63</sup>, that is, the maximum size representable in an `off64_t`. This includes the file representing a process's address space in `proc` (`/proc/<pid>/as`).

To deal with these files:

1. Don't use `fopen`, `fseek`, etc. Don't trust the libc stream routines, which (on the versions of Solaris I tested) mangle badly the "illegal" offsets.
2. Use `open64`, `read`.
3. To seek:

   ```
   static off64_t lseeku64(int file, uint64_t offset /* eg from pr_argv */)
   {
   #ifndef __sun
     if (offset > 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFllu) return -1;
   #endif
     return lseek64(file, offset, SEEK_SET);
   }
   ```

   That is, on Solaris, we know that we can do this cast because of inspection of the OpenSolaris sources, but we should avoid assuming it works on other platforms with `psinfo` and `pr_argv` (eg AIX).

   But, pass in your very large offset, and it does all "just work".